# How to use CDI on TomEE

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, cdi

I'm currently writing JSF code and using Mojarra 2.1.6-FCS, using Tomcat and Eclipse Juno. Now I want to move to CDI, for I discovered it's more practical than JSF.

I need to know stuff like whether I need web.xml and faces-config.xml in order to write and run CDI code; in JSF it's not required.

I just need easy step-by-step instructions for deploying to TomEE. Any flash put into my asking would be way appreciated, thanks a punch.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need web.xml or faces.config.xml just to use CDI. The only thing you need is [beans.xml](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html) (which can be an empty file!), placed inside the `WEB-INF` directory.

I can't give you step-by-step instructions for deploying a CDI application on TomEE, but it should be no different to deploying any other application. Have you read the [TomEE and Eclipse](http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-and-eclipse.html) tutorial?

Comment: hey, I guess I've read link you appointed at above, But not carefully, ended up not able to run standard JSF code, got exceptions, But I will give it another whirl, this time will do the best I can, thanks, sir.

Comment: @RealSilhouette: Good luck! Getting different bits of Java EE to work together can sometimes be difficult; JSF and CDI have not had very long to learn to get along together.

Answer (score 2):

here a sample http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/jsf-cdi-and-ejb/

hope it will help you